# Books for non-statistician?

Tags: references, online-algorithms, careers

I have an educational background of biological sciences. I do not have formal education in mathematics or stats. I have been involved in medical research that has statistical methods like regression, survival analysis, Markov chains or discrete event simulations etc. I have been trying to understand these concepts, not systematically though, however I have developed a keen interest in stats. I want to develop a serious understanding of stats and want to achieve expertise. I understand that this will take years and lot of study and practical experience. I have started with books like Probability by Pitman or Statistics by David Freedman. Could you please suggest me few books, online resources, or other methods for systematically developing an understanding good enough to make a career in data analytics.